# Profile page component does not display on new router link with VueJS route

Tags: vue.js

My goal is to have a list of users and when you click on each user's `first_name` it goes to a new router view called `Profile.vue` where its supposed to show that user's specific information. The problem is the page appears to be blank.

My App looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home Page</router-link> 
      <!-- <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> -->
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

My index.js

```
const routes = [

  {
    path: "/",
    name: "List",
    component: List
  },

  {
    path: "List/profile/:id",
    name: "Profile",
    component: Profile,
    props:true 
  },
```

In List.vue (that uses bootsrap) I have a list of users from an API displayed and I want to click on the first name and open Profile.vue and display each user's information seperately.

```
<template>
  <div class="container mt-4" id="list">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead class="table-dark">
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="user in userList.data" :key="user">
          <v-avatar class="figure"
            ><img :src="user.avatar" alt="Connection lost please reload"
          /></v-avatar>
          <td>
            <router-link :to="'List/profile/' + user.id">{{
              user.first_name
            }}</router-link>
          </td>
          <!-- <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td> -->
          <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
          <th>{{ user.id }}</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>



<script>
export default {
  name: "List",

  data: () => ({
    userList: [],

  }),

  created() {
    fetch("API LINK" + this.$route.params)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.userList = data;
        this.default = [...data.data];
      });
  },

};
</script>




<style>
th {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Profile.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is Profile page number {{ user.id }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Profile",
  props: [
      'user'
  ],
  components: {},

  data: () => ({
    destinationId: this.$route.params.user.id,
  }),

  computed: {
    destination() {
      return this.userList.data.find((user) => user.id == this.destinationId);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is what my homepage looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVjKZ.png

However the page it goes to (example): http://localhost:8080/List/profile/7 is blank.

Comment: You're passing an `id`, but the Profile component expects a `user`

Comment: How do I change it so it searches by id then?

Comment: Well, your Profile.vue also doesn't have access to the `userList` data.  So you could either fetch the data by id, or put `userList` in Vuex and retrieve it from there by id

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way once :**
index.js

```
{
    path: "List/profile/:id",
    name: "Profile",
    component: Profile
  }
```

And in List.vue

```
 <td>
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'Profile', params: { user_id: user.id }}">{{
              user.first_name
            }}</router-link>
          </td>
```

and in Profile.vue
get that id `this.$route.params.user_id`

Comment: It's not enough, Profile.vue doesn't have access to the `userList` data

Comment: it doesn't need to get user list in particular profile view , just by getting id of that profile one can fetch information of him/her and display on profile.vue

Comment: @GunarajKhatri- the approach you provided still leaves the page blank and now the link is not displaying the id

Comment: user.id is not having id value may be try checking manually for surity